# angularjs multiple countdown

Tags: angularjs, countdown

Im in need to make a countdown like this:

```
<div  class="countdown" countdown="1482400417">00:10:02</div>
```

where the countdown attribute is the time when its finished. the difference is showed in hours:minutes:secs , and it updates each second.

How would i do this in angularjs, when i have multiple countdowns like that?

I did a little digging, and i found something that did something simular, but i couldnt understand the code. So ill post the code i found:

```
Travian.Directive.countdown = function(a) {
    return function(c, b, l) {
        function g() {
            if ("undefined" != typeof a.K()) {
                h = b.attr("countdown");
                var c = h - a.K();
                if (0 > c || isNaN(c)) {
                    return Travian.tick.unbind(e), e = null, b.text(
                        la(0)), !1
                }
                var g = "";
                l.showDaysLimit && c >= l.showDaysLimit ? (c = Math
                    .round(c / 86400), c == f ? g = m : (g =
                        Travian.translate("ForDays", {
                            x: c
                        }), f = c)) : g = la(c, l.countdownShort &&
                    c < l.countdownShort);
                m != g && (m = g, b.text(g))
            }
        }
        var h, e = null,
            m = "",
            f = 0;
        l.showDaysLimit && c.$on("newTranslation", function() {
            f = 0
        });
        l.$observe("countdown", function(a) {
            "undefined" != typeof a && null == e && (e =
                Travian.tick.bind(g))
        });
        b.bind("$destroy", function() {
            Travian.tick.unbind(e)
        })
    }
};



  Travian.tick = new function() {
    var a = {};
    (function B() {
      window.setTimeout(B, 100);
      var b = {}, c;
      for(c in a) {
        a.hasOwnProperty(c) && "function" === typeof a[c] && (a[c](), b[c] = a[c])
      }
      a = b
    })();
    return{bind:function(b, c) {
      "function" === typeof b && (c = b, b = na("tick"));
      c();
      a[b] = c;
      return b
    }, unbind:function(b) {
      a[b] = null
    }}
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but that should get you started.

You can create a directive that has and displays a countdown value. This value is updated every second using `$interval` service.

```
myApp.directive('countdown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{countdownVal}}</div>',
        scope: {
            initVal: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope, $interval) {
                $scope.countdownVal = $scope.initVal;

            $interval(function () {
                    if ($scope.countdownVal > 0) {}
                        $scope.countdownVal--;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Having this has a starting point, you can tweak this code to add formatting, and to make this directive usable as an attribute instead of as a element.

See a concrete example in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p4182mb/2/).

Also, keep in mind that you should destroy the interval when you are done with it. From [the docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

> Note: Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed
>   when you are finished with them. In particular they are not
>   automatically destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's
>   element are destroyed. You should take this into consideration and
>   make sure to always cancel the interval at the appropriate moment. See
>   the example below for more details on how and when to do this.

Comment: Sorry I made an error in the JSFiddle. It should work now.

Comment: thanks! will take a look at it now. do you know why it wont show the format? http://jsfiddle.net/4p4182mb/4/

Comment: No problem! It won't work because you did formatting outside of the interval function. You need to do formatting every time the countdown is updated. Keep in mind that this _might_ cause performance as it's executed very often. http://jsfiddle.net/4p4182mb/6/

Comment: thanks @forcent vintier , do you have time to chat? :)

Comment: Yes sure. Also, don't forget to destroy your interval (see edit in post).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122207/discussion-between-maria-and-forcent-vintier).